# changing from ubuntu 12.10 to 14.

Tags: 12.10

First of all I am not experienced in this at all. just learning. but I have a older Lenovo think pad. it has Ubuntu 12.10. I have downloaded the 14. to a flash drive from a windows computer. but when I plug it into the Ubuntu comp, I use the startup disk creator but when I click other because nothing comes up on the top bar, I click on what is downloaded on the flash drive, and it will not do anything. its as if I did not format the flash drive correctly or something. I used the pendrivelinux download software. please help any info and tips is greatly appreciated. also if there is any books I can study and read to get a start on all this would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the **ISO** that you have download, and placed on the USB stick, to the `Downloads` directory on the 12.10 machine.

Now, when you open up the **Startup Disk Creator** from the 12.10 machine, the image (iso) will be in the top box. (`Downloads` is the default directory, `other` is for other directories) The USB stick should be in the lower box.  *Erase Disk*

When it's done deleting everything on the stick.... **Make Startup Disk** and then boot the stick.

Just like the USB stick, unless you have made other preparations all data on the 12.10 machine will be lost as well.

With regards to *what to read*; read everything.  I find a "problem based" strategy the best.  When you have a problem, search for a solution and encompass enough information so you know it should work or at minimum not aggravate the situation.

Comment: When I pull up the make startup disk, it doesn't have anything in the first box. The flash drive is in the bottom one but all I have to click is other. When I do that it shows documents and when I click on the file it just opens into more files I can't select one file to put on the maker. Maybe I formatted the flash drive wrong?

Comment: Have you already *made* the USB stick?  If that is the case then you need to **boot** from the USB http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/bootusbflash.htm  http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Your-Computer-to-Boot-from-USB-Flash-Drive

Comment: Running through scenarios that would explain what you've stated, the most probable is that you have already made the stick, and now you need to boot from it.  This involves modifying the BIOS, if it has been reverted since 12.10 was installed.    Refer to one of the sites in the previous comment, or find another on booting from a USB  that you like better.